# How to place Swiper slider navs inside container (full width slider)

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, swiper.js

How to place right and left arrow inside bootstrap container

https://prnt.sc/10g4f2h ?

If i wrap them inside container has 0px height.

```
        <section class="lead_slider">
            <div class="swiper-lead position-relative">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                        slide 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                        slide 2
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <!-- Add Arrows -->
                    <div class="swiper-button-next d-none d-lg-block"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-button-prev d-none d-lg-block"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- Add Pagination -->
                <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Good morning @Uros Rakic, could you please post some code snippet to help you?

Comment: @JoaoPedro i did